# Convert Json to Ios format

Tags: ios, json, parsing, jsonp

I have try to parse the json in iOS but getting errors.
this is the json which i am getting from the api

```
data =     (
{
LogIn =             {
Emails = "abc@xyz`.com";
Latitude = "37.33233141";
Longitude = "-122.03121860";
Password = 123456;
};
Status = Success;
}
);
```

I want the all details like Emails,Latitude,Longitude and password and also the Status. i am trying the below code for json

```
loginurl= [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
NSLog(@"url is %@",string1);
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loginurl];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

This is my fetch data method -

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{   
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData      options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);
    NSDictionary *data = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *currentConditions = [data objectForKey:@"LogIn"];

    NSDictionary *conditions = [currentConditions objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",conditions);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your JSON format is invalid. It should be like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "LogIn": {
            "Emails": "abc@xyz`.com",
            "Latitude": "37.33233141",
            "Longitude": "-122.03121860",
            "Password": 123456
        },
        "Status": "Success"
    }
}
```

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON data.

Secondly,

```
[data objectForKey:@"LogIn"];
```

is a dictionary, not an array.

Try:

```
NSDictionary *currentConditions = [data objectForKey:@"LogIn"];
NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", [currentConditions objectForKey@"Longitude"]);
```